# Bootstrap 2 columns vertical align + 1 image align left + 1 image align right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not having much success as I've just started playing with bootstrap.
I'm trying to do the following. 
2 columns each with an image that is vertically aligned.  The left column will have the image left aligned and the right column will have the image right aligned.

[image]

So when it is "responsive" it would look like:

[image]

The code that I have just to understand it looks like this - it is vertically aligned but not horizontally aligned properly:

```
 <div class="container" >
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div style="display:table; height:100px;">
                <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; ">
                    <div style="float:left;"> 
                        <img src="http://tarheelreader.org/theme/images/reviewed.png" /> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>              
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div style="display:table; height:100px;">
                <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">
                    <div style="float:right;">
                        <img src="http://tarheelreader.org/theme/images/reviewed.png" /> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
```

It looks like:
[image]

Any suggestions on how I would get it satisfying the first two images above?
thanks!

Comment: can you provide  a fiddle to workout ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you didn't float left or right the good element.

Here is the working code with better class ( `pull-right` and `pull-left` )

```
 <div class="container" >
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div style="display:table; height:100px;" class="pull-left">
                <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; ">
                    <div> 
                        <img src="http://tarheelreader.org/theme/images/reviewed.png" /> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>              
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div style="display:table; height:100px;" class="pull-right">
                <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">
                    <div>
                        <img src="http://tarheelreader.org/theme/images/reviewed.png" /> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
```

**bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/115806

Comment: Thank you so much! I kept thinking float. And i kept trying different variations ... which was definitely wrong. Thanks for your help.